# In Doom the Roguelike is it possible to have 2 master traits?

Tags: doomrl

In DoomRl you can reach a "Master trait", beign one that has several other traits as prerequisite and a few more blocked from picking if you go that route. If such traits are not naturally exclusive (by way of blocked traits), is it possible to reach 2 master traits? For example, **Army of the Dead** and **Survivalist**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found it in the [wiki](https://doom.chaosforge.org/wiki/Traits#Master_Traits) (I was sure I checked that page before asking...). You can't:

> you [can't] choose any other master traits (even if they are technically
>   inclusive of each other).